# How would I access the second child grid in a asp.net grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would I be able to access the second child grid table? I can access the first one with this:

```
GridView gvFirstChild = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("MealPlannerList");
```

But if I try to access the second child by replacing "MealPlannerList" with ItemList, I get a null value. Does anyone have any Idea that could help me access the second gridview?

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="TraineeWeeklyMealList" CssClass="table table-bordered text-left"
        OnRowDataBound="TraineeWeeklyMealList_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="TraineeID" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="FullName" DataNavigateUrlFields="TraineeID"
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Trainer_Webpages/EditTrainee.aspx?TraineeID={0}" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-success btn-xs"
                ItemStyle-CssClass="text-center" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="MealPlannerList" CssClass="table table-bordered text-left"
                        DataKeyNames="MealTraineeID" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DayOfTheWeek" HeaderText="Day of Meal" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="MealType" HeaderText="Meal Type" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="MealName" HeaderText="Meal Name" />
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ItemList" DataKeyNames="FoodID" CssClass="table table-bordered text-left" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="FoodName" HeaderText="Food" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Calories" HeaderText="Calories" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" />
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: that's because any given instance of the second child grid is within the context of a row in the first child (just like an instance of the first child grid is within the context of a row in the parent grid). So you'd have to know which row of the second child you're accessing and then do FindControl within that row, just like you do for the first one. It's exactly the same pattern of behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate down the Control Tree and cast the items back to a GridView along the way. If you do not cast to the GridView you will not be able to use index based FindControl.

```
GridView secondChild = (GridView)((GridView)TraineeWeeklyMealList.Rows[x].FindControl("MealPlannerList")).Rows[y].FindControl("ItemList");
```

Comment: Like I would have to put them in a row loop, and then another row loop?

Comment: That is also a possibility. You need to get the row indexes of both the first and the second GridView before you can access the third.